# How to render listItem of FlatList simultaneously while loading data?

Tags: react-native, search, components

I have {data.word} component.

And, I have data about 100,000 words loading from JSON file.

When searching with this code below. If the result returns 10,000 words. It would take 4-5 seconds. Then, the  just updated respectively.

```
for(let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; ++i) {
            if(data[i].word.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputText) === 0){
                filteredWords.push(glossaries[i]);
            }
}
```

My question is how can I load searching data and start rendering flatlist simultaneously or is there any better code to perform faster searching. (My current app, when I input searching word on searchbox, it takes 4-5 seconds to display the updated flatlist which looks awkward.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100000 entries is quite a lot to search through, especially when you are doing it on a JS runtime on a mobile device that's also responsible for the rest of your app. A few optimisations I'd suggest:

- If you just want to match on the start of the word (eg, "mat" will match "mattress" but "at" won't), look into a data structure like a [Suffix Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pattern-searching-set-8-suffix-tree-introduction/). Implementing this should dramatically speed up your search times.
- I see you're converting all the words to lower case while you're looping through them, try to supply the word data with all the words already in lower case so you don't need to run this operation 100000 times with each keystroke.
- Make sure you're only rendering once and aren't rerendering the list every time a match is found. Only update your component state when you have finished finding strings.

These tweaks should make your app a lot snappier.

Comment: How can I make that the rendering is rendered once. How to set that?